# Why can't I select HTML intellisense options in Visual Studio 2019 (in an ASP.NET Core Project, looking at a cshtml file)?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, intellicode

When I start typing in a cshtml file Visual Studio 2019, if I start with a < then type, I see intellisense options but cannot select them as normal (either by TAB then space or by clicking on them) - why is this? See screenshot below.

Intellisense is appearing but I cannot select it

[image]

My project is an ASP.NET Core one.

Thanks

Comment: Note that if I don't use the angled brackets opening tag, even when I get intellisense, I then have to manually wrap the HTML code with tags, which is not useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have CTRL+M Enabled as this causes tab not to work!
make sure to check this and this may fix your isse.

if this is not the case, then make sure your key is correctly bound. you can do this by:
Going to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

-> Find Edit.InvokeSnippetFromShortcut
-> remove TAB from this and use another shortcut key

Comment: Thanks for this but I should note that intellisense works for C# code I am using in other files in the same project. PS I just checked and Tab is not used in that specific binding on my instance of VS2019.

Comment: Does Ctrl+M you mention refer to this binding Edit.CollapseToDefinitions as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 ?

Comment: Yes, I was, this fixed my issue. it could possibly just be that your compiler is bugged and you just need to restart it.